# Unique value in excel

Tags: excel, unique, cell, formula

I have an array of numbers in Excel spanning from Cells B1 to F49.  Out of all those numbers I want to find out the unique values, in other words, no duplicates.  I tried using Remove duplicates but it looks at the rows and not the individual cells.  What would be my best option for doing this? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please define "find out" - do you want the values highlighted or listed somewhere else.....or something different?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this array formula that returns unique text or numbers from a rectangular range.

1. Select a range to output the results to eg: `H1:H245`
2. Copy and paste the formula below into the formula bar.
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter into the range.

`=IFERROR(CELL("Contents",INDIRECT(T(IF(1,TEXT(MODE.MULT(IF(FREQUENCY(COUNTIF(B1:F49,"<="&B1:F49)+ISTEXT(B1:F49)*COUNT(B1:F49),COUNTIF(B1:F49,"<="&B1:F49)+ISTEXT(B1:F49)*COUNT(B1:F49))>={1,1},MODE.MULT(10^5*ROW(B1:F49)+COLUMN(B1:F49),10^5*ROW(B1:F49)+COLUMN(B1:F49)))),"r0c00000"))),0)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably put this formula in column C: (or another empty column you have):

(so starting in cell C1: )

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,B1)=1
```

(and copy/paste the formula down)

It will return TRUE if it is unique. So you can then filter things out via Filter, or with other formulas down the road.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to just combine your information into one long column and run a remove duplicates. If this is not an option you may want to look at writing a macro to crawl through the records.

You could have a macro go through each column for the rows specified and determine if the CountIf function =COUNTIF(B2:F49,B2) returns a value >1

if it does there are at least 2 instances of this number.

I'm not sure how you want to identify your unique cells but you could potentially set a text color or return the values of the cell to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest for identification of values unique within the entire array may be to highlight the entire range with ‘standard’ formatting of choice for uniques, then select the entire range, Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cell Rules, Duplicate Values…, and choose a custom format of no fill and font of whatever you started with.